# How to get all attribute names, not values of a particular node from the XML?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, marklogic

Suppose I have an XML-

```
<SearchPage ID="123" version="1.3" xmlns="http://some/path">
   .....some child elements
</SearchPage>
```

How to get all the attribute names from it?

Comment: I just realized I did not really improve the question title, but actually missed the "not" and turned the meaning around. Sorry for that! My answer still fits your question, anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `name()` function, or `local-name()` if you want to omit attribute namespaces.

```
let $node := <SearchPage ID="123" version="1.3" xmlns="http://some/path">
               .....some child elements
             </SearchPage>
for $attribute in $node/attribute()
return $attribute/name()
```

with result:

```
ID
version
```

Comment: No that would return the values of attribute not attribute name

Comment: `$some-attribute/name()` returns the attribute's name, not the value.

Comment: just to mention $attribute will have both attribute name and its values.

Comment: But adding `/name()` selects the name of that, which is what you're asking for. I'm not sure what you're having trouble with.